# What is a columnar database?

Tags: sql, database

I have been working with warehousing for a while now.

I am intrigued by Columnar Databases and the speed that they have to offer for data retrievals.

I have multi-part question:

- How do Columnar Databases work?
- How do they differ from relational databases?

Comment: In addition to the reduced # of seeks mentioned in the answers, some implementations (e.g. SQL server’s column store) will compress the data.  This prevents row filtering but can additionally improve query performance.

Comment: FYI: [What makes columnar databases suitable for data science?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/8252/843)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

***How do Columnar Databases work?***
Columnar database is a *concept* rather a particular *architecture/implementation*.  In other words, there isn't one particular description on how these databases work; indeed, several are build upon traditional, row-oriented, DBMS, simply storing the info in tables with one (or rather often two) columns (and adding the necessary layer to access the columnar data in an easy fashion).

***How do they differ from relational databases?***
They generally differ from traditional (row-oriented) databases with regards to ...

- performance...
- storage requirements ...
- ease of modification of the schema ...

***...in specific use cases of DBMSes***.
In particular they offer advantages in the areas mentioned when the typical use is to compute aggregate values on a limited number of columns,  as opposed to try and retrieve all/most columns for a given entity.

***Is there a trial version of a columnar database I can install to play around? (I am on Windows 7)***
Yes, there are commercial, free and also open-source implementation of columnar databases. See the list at the end of the [**Wikipedia article**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columnar_database) for starter.
Beware that several of these implementations were introduced to address *a particular need* (say very small footprint, highly compressible distribution of data, or spare matrix emulation etc.) rather than provide a general purpose column-oriented DBMS per-se.

Note: The remark about the "single purpose orientation" of several columnar DBMSes is not a critique of these implementations, but rather an additional indication that such an approach for DBMSes strays from the more "natural" (and certainly more broadly used) approach to storing record entities.  As a result, this approach is used when the row-oriented approach isn't satisfactory, and therefore and tends to
  a) be targeted for a particular purpose
  b) receive less resources/interest than work on "General Purpose", "Tried and Tested", tabular approach.

Tentatively, the **[Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model)** (EAV) data model, may be an alternative storage strategy which you may want to consider.  Although distinct from the "pure" Columnar DB model, EAV shares several of the characteristics of Columnar DBs.

Answer (score 266):

**How do columnar databases work?**
 The defining concept of a column-store is that the values of a table are stored contiguously by column. Thus the classic supplier table from CJ Date's supplier and parts database:

```
SNO  STATUS CITY    SNAME
---  ------ ----    -----
S1       20 London  Smith
S2       10 Paris   Jones
S3       30 Paris   Blake
S4       20 London  Clark
S5       30 Athens  Adams
```

would be stored on disk or in memory something like:

```
S1S2S3S4S5;2010302030;LondonParisParisLondonAthens;SmithJonesBlakeClarkAdams
```

This is in contrast to a traditional rowstore which would store the data more like this:

```
S120LondonSmith;S210ParisJones;S330ParisBlake;S420LondonClark;S530AthensAdams
```

From this simple concept flows all of the fundamental differences in performance, for better or worse, between a column-store and a row-store. For example, a column store will excel at doing aggregations like totals and averages, but inserting a single row can be expensive, while the inverse holds true for row-stores. This should be apparent from the above diagram.

**How do they differ from relational databases?**
 A relation database is a logical concept. A columnar database, or column-store, is a physical concept. Thus the two terms are not comparable in any meaningful way. Column- oriented DMBSs  may be relational or not, just as row-oriented DBMS's may adhere more or less to relational principles.

Comment: This seems better than the accepted answer, but I'm no expert. Upvote.

Comment: Column oriented databases are used where aggregations on specific columns are queried like sales report. The point here is if you use row oriented database, then all rows (blocks ) needs to be brought to main memory, which includes lots of seek time from disk to bring all block from disk to ram, even if you are interested only in column which helps you to provide sales report. Whereas in column oriented scheme columns are stored contiguously in the blocks, which makes lesser seeks due to less number of blocks. So Column databases are used for OLAP, whereas row oriented are used for OLTP stuff.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the best candidate to understand about column oriented databases is to check HBase ([Apache Hbase](http://hbase.apache.org/)) . You an checkout the code and explore further to find out about the implementation .

Answer (score 2):

Also, Columnar DBs have a built in affinity for data compression, and the loading process is unique.  Here's an [article](http://www.paraccel.com/pdf/Inside%20New-Generation%20Analytic%20DBMS.pdf) I wrote in 2008 that explains a bit more.

You may also be interested in a new report from IDC's Carl Olofson on 3rd generation DBMS technology. It discusses columnar, et al.  If you're not an IDC client you can get it free on our site. He's doing a webinar on June 16th, too (also on our site).

(BTW, one comment above lists asterdata but I don't think they are columnar.)

Comment: You can get the IDC report at: http://paraccel.com/press/3rd_generation_database_technology/

Comment: Aster Data is MPP relational database and it has native support for columnar tables.

Comment: @kimstanick, paraccel URL is dead.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what is column oriented database, it is better to contrast it with row oriented database.

**Row oriented databases** (e.g. MS SQL Server and SQLite)  are designed to efficiently return data for an entire row.  It does it by storing all the columns values of a row together.  Row-oriented databases are well-suited for OLTP systems (e.g., retail sales, and financial transaction systems).

**Column oriented databases** are designed to efficiently return data for a limited number of columns. It does it by storing all of the values of a column together. Two widely used Column oriented databases are Apache Hbase and Google BigTable (used by Google for its Search, Analytics, Maps and Gmail). They are suitable for the big data projects. A column oriented database will excel at read operations on a limited number of columns, however write operation will be expensive compared to row oriented databases.

For more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS

Answer (score 1):

Product information.  This may help.  These were to featured products on a Google search.

http://www.vertica.com/

http://www.paraccel.com/

http://www.asterdata.com/index.php

Comment: One thing to note about Vertica is that I have seen a reference on the web to the license cost being $150k/TB data stored. so it ain't cheap.

Comment: @Mark: Cost is not the issue.  Information is the issue.  If the OP wants information, vendors are often the best possible source.

Comment: Amazon offers its super fast RedShift data storage under $1,000 per terabyte per year if you are not particularly looking for Columnar one.

Answer (score 1):

[kx](http://kx.com/) is another columnar database, for example used in the financial sector. The licence is somewhat $50K last time I checked, though. No optimisation needed, no index needed, because kx has powerful operators (matlab equivalents: `.*`, `kron`, `bsxfun`, ...).