# I want to move data from SQL server DB to Hbase/Cassandra etc.. How to decide which bigdata database to use?

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, cassandra, hbase, bigdata

I need to develop a plan to move data from SQL server DB to any of the bigdata databases? Some of the questions that I have thought of are :

1. How big is the data?
2. What is the expected growth rate for this data?
3. What kind of queries will be run frequently? eg: look-up, range-scan, full-scan etc
4. How frequently the data moved from source to destination?

Can anyone help add to this questionnaire?

Comment: Since SQL Server is relational and HBase is non relational your first question is 'how is this data going to fit in here'

Comment: another could be: do you need to analyse the data or just store it for future use?

Comment: @Whitefret Yes, I will be performing various analysis on this data.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Will it be wise to choose Hive? since it supports HQL which is a SQL kind of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `How big is the data` doesn't matter!  This point barely can be used to decide on which NoSQL DB to use as most NoSQL DBs are made for easy scalability & storage. So all that matters is the ***query you fire*** rather than how much data is there. (Unless of course you intend to use it for storage & access of very small amounts of data because they would be a little expensive in many of the NoSQL DBs) **Your first question must be Why consider NoSQL? Can't RDBMS handle it?**

Expected growth-rate is a considerable parameter but then again not so valid, since most of the NOSQL DBs support storage of large amounts of data (without any scalability issues).

***The most important one in your list is `What kind of queries will be run?`***

This matters most since the **RDBMS stores data as `tuples`** and its easier to select tuples & output them with smaller amounts of data. Its faster at executing `*` queries(as its row-wise storage). But coming to **NoSQL, most DBs are [columnar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133017/what-is-a-columnar-database) or [Column-oriented DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)**.

**Row-oriented system** : As data is inserted into the table, it is assigned an internal ID, the rowid that is used internally in the system to refer to data. In this case the records have sequential rowids independent of the user-assigned empid.

**Column-oriented systems** : A column-oriented database serializes all of the values of a column together, then the values of the next column, and so on.

*Comparisons between **row-oriented** and **column-oriented** databases are typically concerned with the efficiency of hard-disk access for a given workload, as seek time is incredibly long compared to the other bottlenecks in computers.*

`How frequently the data will be moved/accessed?` is again a good question as accesses are costly and few of the NoSQL DBs are very slow the first time a query is shot(Eg: Hive).

**Other parameters you may consider are** :

1. ***Are update of rows(data in the table) required?*** (Hive has problems with updation, you usually have to delete and insert again)
2. ***Why are you using the database?*** *(Search, derive relationships or analytics, etc)* What type of operations would you want to perform on the data?
    Will it require relationship searches? Like in case of Facebook Db(Presto)
    Will it require aggregations?
    Will it be used to relate various columns to derive insights?(like analytics to be done)
3. Last but a very important one, **Do you want to store that data on [HDFS(Hadoop distributed File System)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop#HDFS) as files or your DB's specific storage format or anything else?** This is important since your processing depends on how your data is stored, whether it can be accessed directly or needs a query call which may be time consuming , etc.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ani Menon.

Comment: Does the number of columns in the tables matter in this scenario?

Comment: @DeepakNellurvalappil The number of columns in a table doesn't usually matter when considering a columnar database, but the kind of queries you run can make a difference. Suppose you run something like a `SELECT *` where you use most/all columns then it may cause trouble (if you have too many columns), since most DBs read whole columns into memory when a query(which uses those columns) is run.  [Read this for a better idea of how it all works](http://the-paper-trail.org/blog/columnar-storage/).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Please do share if any more points strike your mind. I will do the same as well here. Thanks.

Comment: @DeepakNellurvalappil Sure.

Answer (score 0):

couple more pointers

1. Type of no-sql DB that suits your requirement. i.e. key-value, document, column family and graph databases
2. CAP theorem to decide which is more critical amongst Consistency, Availability and Partition tolerance